# Linear matrix inequalties with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

I'd like to know how the implement with the LMI Toolbox of MATLAB the following system :

```
$X>0$
$-XA_1^{T}-A_1 X + M_1^{T}B^T+BM_1 > 0$
$-XA_2^{T}-A_2 X + M_2^{T}B^T+BM_2 > 0$
$-XA_1^{T}-A_1 X - XA_2^{T}-A_2 X + M_2^{T}B^T+BM_2 + M_1^{T}B_1^T+BM_1 >0$
```

where the matrices $A_1, A_2 \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ and the matrix $B \in M_{2,1}(\mathbb{R})$. The matrices X and $M_1,M_2$ are the unknown matrices to be determined.

[image]

Comment: @Zheyuan: In the future when adding a rendered version of equations, please don't remove the text (source code) version.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Yes.  We don't want questions asked in images... but question and image together is even better.

Comment: Use Yalmip. Then you can basically type these directly.